# How to make a get method for an arrayList in Java?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, getmethod

How do I make a get method for an ArrayList?

I have the method header but I have no idea how to proceed.

```
 public Object get(int i) {

      }
```

Comment: what language are you using? c# ? The question is not clear

Comment: java, sorry I forgot

Comment: I literally just have no idea on how to proceed

Comment: Is this homework? If so please state that it is. If it's not what is the purpose of this method.

Comment: This is homework. Here are the instructions                    //Returns the element at index i in the arrayList.                    //UML is +get(i: int):Object

Comment: Have you tried solving the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions like this aren't very well-received here. If you're having a specific problem, then we'll be happy to help you. We don't like it when you post homework questions and ask us to do them for you

Comment: Yeah, but I've spent a solid hour thinking about it as well as the rest of the program. I figured that if I can solve this method I can solve the other methods, which include add() and size(). For some reason my professor seems to want us to actually write out the basic methods for an arrayList

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting to return from your get method? In java, ArrayList already has a get on it.. in C# also has a get defined on ArrayList but it is used differently.

I mean... if you are using an ArrayList this would be totally pointless and wrong... And i'm guessing your instructor wouldn't find it funny if you did:

```
public Object get(int i) {
     return myArrayList.get(i);
  }
```

or i mean you could beat around the bush and do this:

```
    public Object get(int i) {
Object[] myArray = new Object[myArrayList.size()];
myArray = myArrayList.toArray(myArray );
return myArray[i];
}
```

Comment: I'm using java but for some reason we are required to write out another get method for our ArrayList. It'll have the exact same function as a normal get method

Comment: It's common when learning to code to write you're own complementation of a existing method so that you gain an understanding of the mechanics of the language. In this case how a Java ArrayList works.

Comment: Ah I see, I figured that since I still had to write a size() that I couldn't use it. Major slip up on my part, thank you so much.